# Having malloced some memory,I could't calculator the proper size of the memories I malloced.I don't know why

Tags: c, malloc, long-integer

Having malloced some memories,I could't calculator the proper size of the memories I malloced.The system told me that I had malloced 2GBytes,but my code told me that I had just malloced 119 MBytes.I dont know what was wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    long long size = 0;
    while(malloc(1) != NULL){
        size = size + 1;
    }
    long long res = size>>20;
    printf("%d MBytes\n",res);

    scanf("%d",&size);
    return 0;
}
```

[image_res_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzS8w.png)
[image_res_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi8Mv.png)

Comment: There's some per-allocation overhead. If you allocate byte by byte, that's going to be proportionally high compared to when you allocate a lot of memory in a single `malloc` call, so the result seems reasonable.

Comment: I hope you unerstand that allocating 1 byte at a time is pointless.

Comment: So while I allocate a byte,a single malloc call will allocate more than a byte at the same time?

Comment: @MichealTenma yes, I don't know how much exactly, but each call to `malloc` allocates probably at least 20 more bytes for internal book keeping.

Comment: I understand it is pointless,but I want to seek for a reason;

Comment: First of all, you might get a signed integer overflow. Second, your program is printing a long long with `%d` so you will just get garbage printed.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well,a single malloc will allocate more than 12bytes additionally.

Comment: You might like to replace `%d` by `%lld` and retest.

Comment: @alk %lld,it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4):

The code for `malloc` and `free` has to maintain data structures keeping track of each block of memory it's given you.  Let's imagine there's a 16-byte data structure per block of memory returned by `malloc`.  You said you allocated 119 MB, which since you allocated 1-byte blocks, suggests you had something like 124780544 blocks.  If each block has 16 bytes of overhead, that's 124780544 x 16 = 1996488704 bytes of overhead.  124780544 + 1996488704 = 2121269248, or just about exactly 2 GB.

(This doesn't *prove* that your system is, in fact, using exactly 16 bytes of overhead for each returned block -- it's probably more complicated than that -- but the result is certainly suggestive.)

The moral is that allocating lots and lots of tiny blocks of memory can be pretty wasteful.

If you change your test program to allocate blocks of, say, 1k at a time, you'll probably get a more palatable result.